# How do I add a cooldown to my Unity teleport

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm sorry for any messy code, I'm relatively new to this. I made a working teleport in Unity but whenever I teleport from one of the teleports to the other, I wanna make it so there's a 5 second cooldown before you can use the teleporter again. So I used IEnumerator, added 5 seconds before "justTeleported" became false again, but when I teleported, I instantly got teleported back, and had to wait 5 seconds before I could try again. So my though was maybe I'm touching the trigger too quickly, before it can become false, that's why I added the two seconds. But now, whenever I get on the teleporter, it goes from true to false to true a couple times, and then I eventually get teleported back to where I came from. If anyone could help, I would be very thankful. Thank you.

```
    {
   public Transform Destination;
    bool justTeleported;
    public GameObject Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    
  
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        justTeleported = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        print(justTeleported)
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player" && justTeleported == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Cooldown");
            

        }
    }

    IEnumerator Cooldown()
    {
        justTeleported = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        Player.transform.position = Destination.transform.position;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5f);
        justTeleported = false;
        
    }
```

Comment: I suppose each of the teleports (entrance & destination) own this script?

Comment: Try to call "justTeleported = true;" before the "StartCoroutine" also when you call the StartCoroutine you don't need tou parse the IEnumerat like a string, so remove the "" characters and last thing try add some "Debug.Log()" inside your Cooldown() method and in your trigger function to see if everything works with the timing

Comment: Why not rather have a script on the player itself for handling the teleport and cooldown?

Comment: Execute the coroutine using the StartCoroutine() function. Is the function called in the update method?

Answer (score 0):

Because each of the teleports has its own `bool justTeleported`, setting the first true doesn't automatically set the other true, so you need some way to tell the Destination teleport script to start it's own cooldown coroutine. Here's my test script, it works for me.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Teleport Destination = null;
    public float CooldownTime = 5f;
    private bool justTeleported = false;
    
    public void StartCoolDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Cooldown());
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !justTeleported) //CompareTag("tag") is better than .tag == "tag"
        {
            TeleportPlayer(coll.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void TeleportPlayer(GameObject player)
    {
        if (Destination) //if Destination is not null
        {
            StartCoolDown();
            Destination.StartCoolDown(); //tell Destination to cooldown
            player.transform.position = Destination.transform.position;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Cooldown()
    {
        justTeleported = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(CooldownTime);
        justTeleported = false;
    }
}
```

Teleport1 (Destination: Teleport2)
[image]
Teleport2 (Destination: Teleport1)
[image]